# Having trouble making transfer function from this Bode plot from op Amp datasheet in Mathematica

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-system, transfer-function, bode-plot

I am fairly green to control theory.
I am trying to reproduce the Open loop transfer function of the LT1X28 op amp in mathematica.
I want to get the poles and zeros from the following plots and produce a very similar response with a bode plot. This way I can compensate for the pole-zero doublet that causes ringy-dingy-ness at higher frequencies. Below is the code for how I setup the transfer-function. The parameters are in Hz.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone point me in the correct direction or help out? I believe I am doing something incorrect whether it be mixing up angular frequency and Hz or something.I am getting similar plots but not correct results. The Gain plot looks good but the Phase plot is very inconsistent with the x-axis on the datasheet. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Code for copy/paste:

```
params1028 = {Avol1028 = 146.0, GBW1028 = 75.0 10^6, 
   DominantPole1028 = 4.5, SecondPole1028 = 500 10^3, 
   ThirdPole1028 = 26.25 10^6, FirstZero1028 = 2.5 10^6};
GofS[Avol_, p1_, p2_, p3_, z1_] := 
 TransferFunctionModel[
  10^(Avol/20) (
   1 + s/(2 \[Pi] z1))/((1 + s/(2 \[Pi] p1)) (1 + s/(2 \[Pi] p2)) (1 +
       s/(2 \[Pi] p3))), s]
Trans1028 = 
  GofS[Avol1028, DominantPole1028, SecondPole1028, ThirdPole1028, 
   FirstZero1028];
BodePlot[Trans1028[2 \[Pi] s], {2 \[Pi] 1 10^-1, 2 \[Pi] 1 10^8}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
BodePlot[Trans1028[2 \[Pi] s], { 2 \[Pi] 1 10^4,  2 \[Pi] 1 10^7}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: The log frequency scale should go up in decades: 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, ...etc

Comment: well 10^5 Hz @ the dip, on the mathematica phase plot, is nowhere near the 2.5MHz dip on the phase plot of the datasheet. That is the problem

Comment: **1** The legend on the right axis is labelled `Phase Margin (deg)` ??? Are you accounting for that ?  **2** Are you checking the plot visually ? How well is the gain matching really ? **3** How did you calculate the poles zero locations ? trial and error ? Since the original plot is very much compressed in the x axis, and since the roll off seems steep, small changes in gain can cause big changes in phase.

Comment: @AJN 1. Yes I compare the phase margin to the phase shift by subtracting by 180 degrees. 2. yes I am checking by analyzing x and y points on the gain, really small changes must be occurring because it is near impossible to doubt the gain plot. 3. I eyeballed the poles and zero locations because they are not given in the datasheet. The xaxis just looks to be a couple mega hertz off for some reason. I just can't seem to get the poles and zeros right I guess.

Comment: **1** Since phase shows more variation in the 1M to 10M range, why not try to fit the phase with the guessed poles and zeroes (and see if gain plot automatically matches). With the drawn scale, gain may be less sensitive to poles and zero location compared to phase. **2** Also, try a graph to data converter to get data and then do system identification on that if you are comfortable with that. **3** From my experience, it is very difficult to fit a transfer function model to measured data perfectly, since actual system can have pure time delays which will not fit well with finite degree TF.

Comment: I plotted the LT 1028 response and the model response and i can find upto 2dB difference in the gain response (at 2MHz). Perhaps that's not good enough to get a match in phase ? The phase response of the model is *shallow*. May be we need complex conjugate pole pairs instead of real poles to get steeper transitions in phase?

Comment: @AJN 1. Yes, I've been trying that but I can't seem to get the dip and peak in the phase aligned. 2. data converter you mean like SPICE? What poles  and zeros did you choose,? Yeah I am fairly new to the subject but I assume you are saying that the real pole model is too smooth? 2dB difference in gain seems enough, phase margin is whats important

Comment: By converter I meant [Link 1](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) or [Link 2](http://www.graphreader.com/) to *get* numeric data out of the image. But the *conversion* can itself add error in the gain / phase data. [numbers](https://pastebin.com/AZ6sz5UV). The change in phase after 1M seems very steep to be made out of real poles; But I'm not sure. That's why i suggest system identification methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111909/discussion-between-ajn-and-joshua-girgis).

Comment: @joshua please ask a specific question